# How to do an automatic search if user pauses input for 1-2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have a `form_tag` that submits a user's search remotely to a Rails controller method, which returns the results in JS format.

How can I automatically submit this form:

1. When a user has entered in at least 2 characters
2. When the user has paused for at least 1 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a keypress handler to the input using jQuery. In the callback, start a timer using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to submit the form after one second and keep a hold of the timer ID that `setTimeout` returns to you. If you have a non-null timer ID when your keypress callback is triggered, stop the timer with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) and set the timer ID to null; if they also have two characters at this point, then start the timer (again) and store the timer ID (again).

So, you have a process in the keypress handler like this:

1. Do I have a timer running?

   - If yes, `clearTimeout`, null the timer ID, and continue.
   - If no, then continue on.
2. Do I have at least two characters?

   - If yes, start the timer with `setTimeout` and store the timer ID, the function attached to the timer would submit the form.
   - If no, then continue on.
3. ...
4. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I think @mu's answer is great, but I would like to take the moment to recommend an autocomplete input field. I am currently maintaining one myself, it is called [Better Autocomplete](https://github.com/betamos/Better-Autocomplete). It can handle your server's response, despite what data it returns. Other, more widespread scripts, are [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) and [another third party jQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).